# I'm trying to bring in some images from my resources folder and i keep getting an error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub tmrChangeImage_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrChangeImage.Tick

    Const intMAXIMAGES As Integer = 5
    Dim imgPictures(intMAXIMAGES - 1) As Image
    Dim intImage As Integer
    imgPictures(1) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flipbook_1_bio")
    imgPictures(2) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flipbook_2_bio")
    imgPictures(3) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flipbook_3_bio")
    imgPictures(4) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("flipbook_4_bio")




    PictureBox.Image = Properties.Resources.flipbook__1__bio
    intImage = (intImage + 1) Mod intMAXIMAGES
End Sub
End Class
```

My error is right after PictureBox.Image = that finish line throws me off

Comment: Please keep in mind i put some lines in comment mode just until i get the others working.

Comment: Go on, tell us what the errors are exactly...

Comment: Error 1 Local variable 'intMAXIMAGES' is already declared in the current block. H:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WEGOTAJUMPER\WEGOTAJUMPER\Form1.vb 33 16 WEGOTAJUMPER        error one deals with intMAXIMAGES

Comment: Error 2 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. H:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WEGOTAJUMPER\WEGOTAJUMPER\Form1.vb 35 9 WEGOTAJUMPER     error two deals with Picturebox.image

Comment: Error 3 'Properties' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. H:\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WEGOTAJUMPER\WEGOTAJUMPER\Form1.vb 35 28 WEGOTAJUMPER        error three deals with Properties.

Comment: Error1: Remove that line, or remove `Const intMAXIMAGES As Integer = 5`. The two lines are declaring the same identifier. Error2: Verify that your picture box is actually called `PictureBox`. The compiler thinks you're referring to the `PictureBox` class. Error3: You're probably missing an `Imports` with the namespace of the project's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have declared intMAXIMAGES twice, once in the Dim statement and once in the Static statement.
2. Do you mean PictureBox1 instead of PictureBox?